# Best Practice when using $scope properties in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m working on an application and I’m trying to make sure I’m using `$scope` correctly.

I watched the best [practices video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) and Miško kinda says we shouldn’t be manipulating `$scope` properties in this.

I’ve been creating variables like this for the most part:

```
    $scope.groups = groupService.getGroups()
    $scope.users = userService.getUsers();
    $scope.selectedUser = false;
```

Should I re-write my application to use something like this instead:

```
    $scope.model = {
        selectedAvailableGroups: [],
        selectedAssignedGroups: [],
        allGroups: groupService.getGroups(),
        allUsers: userService.getUsers(),
        selectedUser: false
    }
```

The reason I ask is that I’ve rarely seen examples or applications using `$scope.model` way, it’s usually just properties declared on `$scope`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always have a period in your model names because of the way that javascript searches the inheritance chain. I would advise you refactor as you are suggesting.

To be clear, when you set a primitive property on a javascript object like:

```
$scope.Name ='Fred'
```

If Name doesn't exist javascript will create a new property without checking the parent object.

If you do like this:

```
$scope.Model.Name = 'Fred'
```

javascript will check the parent(s) all the way up until it either finds Model.Name or finds it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I follow very lean controller. service and model holds most of the functionality. Maintaining and creating unit test will be easier.
I create model POCO class separately like.

```
var groups= {
   this.a='';
   this.b='';
};
```

service looks like

```
mymodule.service('myservice',[function(){
   var mymodel=_.extend(new groups, <anyothermodels>);
    return mymodel
})];
```

my controller look like

```
mymodule.controller('mycontroller',['myservice','$scope',function(myservice,scope){
 $scope.model= myservice;
})];
```

Comment: ur $scope.model holds your entire service?

Comment: @Batman yeah, models and action methods which I may need to invoke from view.

Comment: Wow...I've got about 50-100 lines in my controllers. You have like 2 :/

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends on the context of your application.

For instance, if your controller was to iterate over all groups via ng-repeat or similar, it would make sense to attach it to the scope.  Same for iterations over all the users.

Remember, attach things to $scope that you want to use in your view (HTML).  While it's been said that making a service can make things easier in some cases, it does make sense to attach an array to $scope.

Given your context, I'm not sure what you are doing with the 'groups' or 'users' arrays, but if you're going to use them in the DOM, attach them to the scope.  Anything more complex than that I would suggest refactor it all into a service.  For instance if you were trying to find all the groups a selected user was involved in:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, UserService, GroupService) {
        var users = UserService.getUsers();
        var groups = GroupService.getGroups();
        $scope.selectedUser = null;

        $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
            $scope.selectedUser = user;
            $scope.groups = groups.filter(function (group) {
                return group.users.indexOf(user) >= 0;
            };
        }

    });
```

And then in your HTML

```
<ul class="userList">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="userGroupList" ng-show="selectedUser">
    <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
        {{group.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well yea most of these properties end up on the DOM in my application. All users is in a select element as a dropdown list, all groups is used to allow the application user to add or remove a user from a group. I use them with ngRepeat or ngOptions. All the data is coming from the service though, from them I use the controller to get the object and the view renders the data.

Comment: Your html is basically what I had but now I'd added model.user.name, model.group.name etc etc. It's kind of annoying to do so. It's hard for me to see the benefit of doing that, other than "that's what you're suppose to do just in case something something"